# Unwanted prefix in soap request

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, asmx

I create a webService in C# and I'm having a response a little different then I was expecting. Seem that part of the name space it's been used as a "prefix" in my soap nodes.

This is part of my WSDL:

```
  <s:complexType name="IncidentCreatedStc">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CreationDate" type="s:dateTime" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:element name="IncidentCreatedResponse">
```

This is the request expected I see in the browner:

```
POST localhost/PowerOn2SCADAWebservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "ENMAC/TCS/IncidentCreated"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<IncidentCreated xmlns="ENMAC/TCS">
      <CreationDate>string</CreationDate>
     </IncidentCreated>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But if I send this XML the field CreationDate will be empty, but if I send:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tcs="ENMAC/TCS/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tcs:IncidentCreated>
         <tcs:CreationDate>2012-01-01</tcs:CreationDate>
      </tcs:IncidentCreated>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then it work fine, the problem is that the program I'm interfacing with does not send the soap message with a XML like this, so I need to find a way to remove this "prefix" tcs from the request.

The code is:

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "ENMAC/TCS")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]


    public class PowerOnGatewayService : System.Web.Services.WebService

...
        [WebMethod]
        public string IncidentCreated (string CreationDate)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Most of the code was auto-generated by Visual Studio, I don't know if those parts will help

Any ideas where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You showed part of the WSDL, but didn't show any of the code in your service! Show the data type that's being returned, at least. BTW, your problem isn't the prefix. The problem is that the `IncidentCreated` element is in the wrong namespace. It seems that you want it to be in the `http://www.tvd.co.nz` namespace, but it's in the `ENMAC/TCS/` namespace. A prefix is only an alias for a namespace.

Comment: Thanks John, I update the post, the web address was my first Namespace, but the message has returning 500 I guess because the expected action is ENMAC/TCS, now returns 200 but does not read any of the values in the XML.

Comment: One of the things that you're "doing wrong" is that you are using ASMX. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: You said that the program you're interfacing with "does not send the soap message with a XML like this". Please show the XML it is sending.

Comment: Meaning that the XML I'm receiving does not have the "prefix" so I need to remove it somehow.

Comment: No, you don't. You need to understand about XML namespaces, and you need to put your elements into the correct namespace. The prefix doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I use Soap UI to send the request and when I use <tcs:IncidentCreated><tcs:CreationDate>2012-01-01</tcs:CreationDate></tcs:IncidentCreated> work and when I use this <IncidentCreated><CreationDate>2012-01-01</CreationDate></IncidentCreated> does not, note the only difference is the tcs: noting else change

Comment: I both cases the request work but in the second case I have a null value, I'm guessing the biding is not matching in c#, however iis accept the request as correct

Comment: You didn't define `tcs` in SoapUI. Is there a `xmlns:tcs="ENMAC/TCS/"` in your request in soapUI?

Answer (score 0):

Prefix is taken from the default namespace in your WCF service. If you want to change the prefix tag use the namespace element in your class attribute like below

```
[DataContract(Namespace ="")]

    public class UPDATED_ACCOUNT_DETAILS_REQUEST : BASENEW
    {
        [DataMember(Order =3)]
        public string MSISDN { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public string IMSI { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public string ICC_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

You can even give your prefix tag in [datacontract(namespace="ctc")]